# Processing: How to make Sphere that rotates when mouseClicked?

Tags: java, rotation, processing

In my program, I want a sphere to represent a globe. I want the user to press down the mouse1 button and rotate the sphere. When the user is not pressing the mouse1 down, the sphere should just be staying still regardless of how the mouse is moving. In simple terms, I want a sphere to rotate only when the mouse is pressed. Here is my code for the sphere rotating.

```
float lockXRotation;
float lockYRotation;

void setup() {
    size(1000,700,P3D); //reference
}

void draw() {
    mouseAction();
    fill(200, 0, 160);

    if(mousePressed == false){
        rotateX(lockXRotation);
        rotateY(lockYRotation);
    }
    sphere(100);
}

void mouseAction () {
    translate(500, 350, 0); //reference starts here'
    if(mousePressed){
        rotateX(mouseY * -0.01);
        rotateY(mouseX * -0.01); //ends here
        lockXRotation = 0;//what should i put so it will stay still?
        lockYRotation = 0;
    }
}
```

I have tried mouseX * -0.01 for lockXRotation but it offsets by the distance of the x to the origin. Is there a function to find the rotation an object is in?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want the sphere's location to lock when the user presses the mouse.

I took a look at your code and ran it on Processing, I believe that your `lockXRotation` is not doing what it is suppose to.

If you look at lines 12 - 15, where it says `if (mousePressed == false)`, then it should `rotateX(lockXRotation)`, those lines don't belong in the draw function, but if you put them in the `mouseAction` function, that might solve the problem.